# Post Images to fillable image field of a .pdf using python

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation

I have looked into pypdf and fitz (PyMuPDF) packages, and they have different uses.

I can use pypdf to find all the fillable fields:

```
# Create a PDF reader object
pdf_reader = pypdf.PdfReader(pdf_file)

# Get the PDF form object
pdf_form = pdf_reader.get_form_text_fields()
```

I can post text:

```
# Fill in the fields with the desired values
pdf_form['Title'] = 'Value 1'
pdf_form['Subtitle'] = 'Value 2'

# Save the updated PDF file
pdf_writer = pypdf.PdfWriter()
pdf_writer.add_page(pdf_reader.pages[0])
pdf_writer.update_page_form_field_values(pdf_writer.pages[0], pdf_form)
output_file = open('output.pdf', 'wb')
pdf_writer.write(output_file)
```

I can't figure out pictures with this library. In contrast, PyMuPDF makes posting images simple enough:

```
def place_image(file_name, x, y, input_pdf_path, output_map_path, page_number, width=10, height=10, **kwargs):
    """
    Place image on the pdf document. Use the get_coordinate_map
    function to help with placement.
    Parameters
    ---------
    file_name: str
        The path of the file to be placed in the image
    x: float
        The x coordinate of the top left corner of the text.
    y: float
        The y coordinate of the top right corner of the text.
    input_pdf_path: str
        Path to the pdf you want the fields from.
    output_map_path: str
        Path of the new pdf that is generated.
    page_number: float
        Number of the page to get the map of.
    width: float
        The width of the image
    height: float
        The height of the image
    kwargs: Dict
        Additional arguments to pass to fitz save method.
    Returns
    ---------
    """
    doc = fitz.open(input_pdf_path)
    page = doc[page_number-1]
    
    page.insert_image(fitz.Rect(x, y, x+width, y+height), filename=file_name)
    doc.save(output_map_path, **kwargs)
```

(that code was from [fillpdf](https://github.com/t-houssian/fillpdf) which used the fitz library really cleanly). I struggled to place the images in the right place though.

To bridge the gap, fillpdf created the following support function to place images:

```
def get_coordinate_map(input_pdf_path, output_map_path, page_number=1, **kwargs):
    """
    Creates a map on the pdf page to help in the placement of text, photos,
    and widgets.
    Parameters
    ---------
    input_pdf_path: str
        Path to the pdf you want the fields from.
    output_map_path: str
        Path of the new pdf that is generated.
    page_number: float
        Number of the page to get the map of.
    kwargs: Dict
        Additional arguments to pass to fitz save method.
    Returns
    ---------
    A dictionary of form fields and their filled values.
    """
    doc = fitz.open(input_pdf_path)
    page = doc[page_number-1]
    max_x = page.rect[2]
    max_y = page.rect[3]
        
    for y in range(0, int(math.ceil(max_y / 50.0)) * 50, 50): # Drop a dot every 20 px x and y
        page.insert_text(fitz.Point(0 , y), str(y), fontsize=12, fontname="times-bold", color=(1, 0, 0))
        page.draw_line(fitz.Point(0 , y), fitz.Point(max_x , y), color=(1, 0, 0))
        
    for x in range(0, int(math.ceil(max_x / 50.0)) * 50, 50):
        page.insert_text(fitz.Point(x , 12), str(x), fontsize=12, fontname="times-bold", color=(1, 0, 0))
        page.draw_line(fitz.Point(x , 12), fitz.Point(x , max_y), color=(1, 0, 0))
    
    doc.save(output_map_path, **kwargs)
```

which marks the image up with lines and denotes the position of these lines.

Does anyone know an easier way to post images into image fields? I am not even sure I know how to use code to find the coordinate or size of my image fields to try to place an image ontop of the field.

Comment: What is your problem with image insertion exactly: it requires tha page, the target rectangle on that page and the image itself. How could this be simpler to do?

Comment: I would like to post a picture into a fillable image form field. This will allow me to generate PDFS without being the one to design them. The fields also have some default behavior regarding resizing and image and keepings its aspect ratio. Sounds like I may need to just place the images with fitz which will be more work and not allow me to collaborate as easier with someone who takes on a designing role of the pdf being generated.

Comment: Ok. Well you cannot "fill" PDF fields with images - not with PyMuPDF at least.
But you could use the field rectangle `field.rect` and insert an image in that rectangle - as some type of background so to say.

Comment: Yea.. it requires knowing coordinates and deciding the image width and height in pixels. I was trying to avoid that and have it auto scale to the image field in the part of the pdf designated for the image. But maybe I am asking too much, thanks for your time

Comment: No worries here: You need not do anything by yourself. Just take the field rectangle to insert the image into. Scaling happens automatically. However, the aspect ratio will be kept by default, and the field area thus not be completely covered. If you want to change that , set argument `keep_proportion=False` and the image will also be streched as needed.